# Json Server returns 404 with "put" or "patch", "get" works fine

Tags: angular, typescript, https, http-headers, json-server

Im changing the information (`skills: SkillSet[]`) from the [server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2SrR.jpg) inside the [component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3gRK.jpg) with a couple inputs, in the browser. I would like to decide with two buttons whether to update or not the server with these changes. Can't make the saveChanges function work.

Skills component save changes function:

```
saveChanges(): void {
    this.editMode = false;
    this.skillsService.saveChanges(this.skills).subscribe();
  }
```

Skills service save changes function:

```
// Update changes made by the component
  saveChanges(skills: SkillSet[]): Observable<SkillSet[]> {
    console.log(skills); // Proof the array is returning with the edits.
    return this.http.patch<SkillSet[]>(
      this.skillsUrl,
      skills,
      this.httpOptions
    );
  }
```

When using the button the console responds [PATCH http://localhost:5000/skills 404 (Not Found)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYMmW.jpg) It also doesn't work with put. And the url works, otherwise I the template never gets the data in the first place. [Network / Fetch/XHR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnHla.jpg)
Please let me know if more information is needed.

--- All the code ---

SkillSet interface

```
export interface SkillSet {
  id: number;
  type: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  tools: string[];
}
```

Skills component (entire code):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { SkillSet } from 'src/app/interfaces/skill-set';
import { SkillsService } from 'src/app/services/skills.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-skills',
  templateUrl: './skills.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./skills.component.scss'],
})
export class SkillsComponent implements OnInit {
  login: boolean = true;
  editMode: boolean = false;

  skills: SkillSet[] = [];
  newTool: string = '';

  constructor(private skillsService: SkillsService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getSkills();
  }

  getSkills() {
    this.skillsService
      .getSkills()
      .subscribe((skills) => (this.skills = skills));
  }

  // Edition functions of this section
  addTool(skillSet: SkillSet, tool: string) {
    if (tool) {
      skillSet.tools.push(tool);
    }
  }
  deleteTool(skillSet: SkillSet, tool: string) {
    skillSet.tools = skillSet.tools.filter((t) => t !== tool);
  }

  // Changes menu
  editStart() {
    this.editMode = true;
    console.log('Editing skills');
  }
  saveChanges(): void {
    this.editMode = false;
    this.skillsService.saveChanges(this.skills).subscribe();
  }
  cancelChanges() {
    this.editMode = false;
    this.getSkills();
  }
}
```

Skills service (entire code):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

import { SkillSet } from '../interfaces/skill-set';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SkillsService {
  private skillsUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/skills';

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }),
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getSkills(): Observable<SkillSet[]> {
    return this.http.get<SkillSet[]>(this.skillsUrl);
  }

  // Update changes made by the component
  saveChanges(skills: SkillSet[]): Observable<SkillSet[]> {
    console.log(skills); // Proof the array is returning with the edits.
    return this.http.patch<SkillSet[]>(
      this.skillsUrl,
      skills,
      this.httpOptions
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You’re not telling json-server what id you want to patch? That might be the issue.

Comment: What is the definition of the PATCH request? Does it expect an array? Normally it will expect and ID of the row changed and a body with changed fields

Comment: I would like the entire skills section of the server (which also contains other arrays) to be updated with this function.
The skills section contains 3 SkillSets, for which I made a TS interface , these are edited in the component. Can I update the server maybe even if only one of them received changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JSON-Server you can only update 1 item per http call. Commonly you will use it like this:

```
http.patch(`{this.url}/{idToUpdate}`, bodyWithUpdate)
```

If that Item is a complete structure then you can update the complete structure, but by the looks of it you do not have that.

Either change the structure that json server returns or find the changed items in the skillset and call the patch request several times.

Something like this:

```
skills.forEach((skill)=>{
   if (skill.changed){
       http.patch(`{this.url}/{skill.id}`, skill);
   }
})
```

Comment: the db.json has the skills (array of skillsets) and also experiences, educations, proyects...
That isn't a complete structure is it?
I was hoping to update each section all at once after the edits made on each component.
If its a limitation of the server I will carry on because its just temporary. Thanks.

Comment: I could imagine a structure like {id:1, name:charlie, skilset:[{id:1, skill:typescript},{id:2,skill:angular}]}. Then all the skills are nested in a student and can be updated in 1 call. However you still need to provide an id (of the student) to update those skills. And if Students share the same skill you will have duplicates.